# what does $a = new $b() mean in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

Although I get it that

```
$a = new b()
```

would be initializing an object for the class b, but what would

```
$a = new $b()
```

mean because I came across some code that happens to work otherwise!

Comment: I'm not quite sure, as you've said $a = new b() would initialize class b, I don't actually think $a = new $b() should work... 

Strange, I hope to find the answer also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a reflexive reference to the class with a name that matches the value of `$b`.

Example:

```
$foo = "Bar";

class Bar
{
   ...code...
}

$baz = new $foo();

//$baz is a new Bar
```

**Update** just to support: you can call functions this way too:

```
function test(){
    echo 123;
}
$a = "test";
$a(); //123 printed
```

Comment: That's strange, but I suppose it makes sense, what possible advantage could that have over $baz = new Bar(); though?

Comment: @LukeBerry, the advantages are in inheritance and extensibility. If I make a CMS i could allow users to provide plugin classes and specify the names of the enabled ones in a database. I could then instantiate *all* the enabled plugins reflexively by iterating over the names. It has niche uses, but *significantly* improves the modularity of code. I never need to know the name of the class I'm making in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
$b = "Foo";
$a = new $b();
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
$a = new Foo();
```

Meaning that you can use syntax like `$b()` to dynamically refer to a function name or a class name.